# Send HTML based on browser (iPhone or other)

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have an image carousel on a page on my site (using slidesjs and jQuery). It works fine on all desktop browsers, and even on the iPhone if the phone is on wireless. When the iPhone is connecting via 3G or GPRS, the image area of the carousel doesn't load and there's just blank white space.

However, I believe that the size of the images is stopping things from loading.

So what I'd like to do is detect whether or not the user is using mobile Safari, and if so, just show a single image in this space.

To do that means changing the HTML that is output for the carousel and just setting it to a single image source.

Is it possible to do this with javascript somehow ?

Comment: A note: I disagree with your conclusions, and I think that doing a browser detect and changing the nature of the site instead of addressing the underlying problem is bad practice.  You'll spend as much time getting this set up as you would have spent figuring out the original problem.... don't make NEW problems for yourself! :)

Comment: I do agree with this comment, despite my answer below. It is quite possible you will be faced with the same problem again. Browser detection is a last resort one hour before a customer demo deadline, but pretty much never a good solution. It also looks like you have a timing issue, and need to adjust the script to wait for the images to come and be ready first. Try to throttle the connection to imitate slow response from the network on any desktop browser, I am sure you will see this problem again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy to do. Full explanation is here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html.
Just look for "iPhone" in `navigator.userAgent` string.

Comment: [Browser detection](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/detect-browser/) is never a good idea.The issue isn't even related to the browser but apparently to how it connects.